# Using Spring Pageable, how to sort column order by using a checkbox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting

I have a basic Spring Boot program to test Pageable filtering and sorting, a user can search for a specific entry using a keyword in this case, or click the table header to sort by specific column in descending/ascending order. However, I want also to add the option to sort the columns by clicking radio buttons. I'm not sure how to implement it.

This is the thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Management System</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container my-2">
    <h1>Employees List</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/}">
            Filter: <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="50" th:value="${keyword}" required />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClear" onclick="clearSearch()" />
        </form>
    <a th:href = "@{/showNewEmployeeForm}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"> Add Employee </a><br>

        <table border="1" class = "table table-striped table-responsive-md">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=firstName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                        Employee First Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=lastName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Last Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=email&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Email</a>
                    </th>
                    <th> Actions </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="employee : ${listEmployees}">
                    <td th:text="${employee.firstName}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${employee.lastName}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${employee.email}"></td>
                    <td> <a th:href="@{/showFormForUpdate/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/deleteEmployee/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div th:if = "${totalPages > 1}">
            <div class = "row col-sm-10">
                <div class = "col-sm-2">
                    Total Rows: [[${totalItems}]]
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}" style="display: flex;">
                        <a th:if="${currentPage != i}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${i}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                        <span th:unless="${currentPage != i}">[[${i}]]</span>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Next</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${totalPages}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Last</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearSearch() {
        window.location = "[[@{/}]]";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is a method called findPaginated() which accepts four parameters: pageNo, pageSize, sortField, and sortDirection.

The method returns a Page of Employee objects.

The method first creates a Sort object based on the sortField and sortDirection parameters. If the sortDirection is "asc", the Sort object will be sorted in ascending order, otherwise, it will be sorted in descending order.

Next, the method creates a Pageable object based on the pageNo, pageSize, and sort parameters using the static factory method PageRequest.of().

Finally, the method uses the employeeRepository object to call the findAll() method with the pageable parameter and returns the result.

```
public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
        Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
            Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
        return this.employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

This is a method called searchEmployees() that accepts five parameters: pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir, and keyword.

The method returns a Page of Employee objects.

The method first creates a Sort object based on the sortField parameter, and then sorts it in ascending or descending order based on the sortDir parameter.

Next, the method creates a Pageable object based on the pageNo, pageSize, and sort parameters using the static factory method PageRequest.of().

Then, the method checks if the keyword parameter is not null and not empty. If it is not null and not empty, the method calls the findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining() method on the employeeRepository object with the keyword parameter and the pageable parameter. This method will return a Page of Employee objects whose first name or last name contains the keyword.

```
public Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword) {
        Sort sort = Sort.by(sortField);
        sort = sortDir.equals("asc") ? sort.ascending() : sort.descending();

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);

        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeRepository.findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(keyword, keyword, pageable);
        } else {
            page = employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
        }

        return page;
    }
```

The two previous methods are implemented from the Service class:

```
Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection);

Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword);
```

This is a controller method that handles GET requests to the "/page/{pageNo}" endpoint, where "{pageNo}" is a path variable that represents the page number to be displayed. It accepts the path variable "pageNo", query parameters "sortField", "sortDir", and "keyword", and a Model object.

The method first sets the pageSize to 10, which is the number of items to be displayed on each page. Then, depending on whether keyword is null or empty, it calls the appropriate method from the employeeService to retrieve a Page of Employee objects that match the specified criteria.

The Model is then updated with various attributes that are used in the view. These attributes include the current page number, the total number of pages, the total number of items, the sort field and direction, the search keyword, the reverse sort direction, and the list of Employee objects to be displayed on the current page.

```
@GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                @RequestParam("sortField") String sortField,
                                @RequestParam("sortDir") String sortDir,
                                @RequestParam(value = "keyword", required = false) String keyword,
                                boolean sort, Model model) {
        int pageSize = 10;

        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeService.searchEmployees(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir, keyword);
        } else {
            page = employeeService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        }
        List<Employee> listEmployees = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", listEmployees);
        return "index";
    }
```

This is a controller method that handles GET requests to the "/" (root) endpoint. It accepts a Model object and a query parameter keyword with an optional value.

The method then calls the findPaginated() method with the arguments 1 for the page number, "firstName" for the sort field, "asc" for the sort direction, keyword for the search keyword (if it's not null or empty), and model to add attributes to the model object.

Finally, the method returns the name of the view that should be used to display the results, which is "index" in this case.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model, @Param("keyword") String keyword) {
        return findPaginated(1, "firstName", "asc", keyword, model);
    }
```

If any additional code or context is need please let me know, however a lot of this project was pulled from: https://github.com/RameshMF/springboot-thymeleaf-crud-pagination-sorting-webapp